# Query Tools and Settings

Tags: ms-access

I need some assistance with Expression builder in an Access Query.

*Please Note: I am currently working from Design View*

I have the following expression written "SumofQuantity: [QuantitySold]>=10". I am try to pull from my column "QuantitySold" that have sold 10 or more items.  The column lives under the table Orderline

Also my second questions is from the bottom section of Design View:

My query only gives me the options of FIELD, TABLE, SORT, SHOW, CRITERIA, and OR. Does anyone know how to add the TOTAL option? I need to switch some to "group by" and "sum".

Thank you!

```
SumofQuantity: [QuantitySold]>=10
```

Comment: Hi @GB1 and welcome to SO :-) Please always try to a different post for each of your questions, it makes it easier for everyone.

Comment: To get the total option, in Design View, in your ribbon panel click in the epsilon symbol `Ʃ`

Answer (score 0):

In Design View, you can use a query similar to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMWrj.png).

The Criteria column is where you need to put your ">= 10" *criteria*. It is essentially a WHERE clause without the target column since that is identified by the column you're working in.